# Update the view (html) in angular shared component

Tags: angular

I have a shared component and it is been used by two modules.My requirement is to hide a input text box in shared component for one module.
How to handle this.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by checking the Route URL.

```
 showInputField : boolean = false;
    this.router.url === "/firstModule" ? this.showInputField = true : this.showInputField = false;
```

Add the above line in `ngOnInit()`  of your shared component.

I hope this works fine

Comment: Thanks Tej for the reply..   the code works well for sure. For example the shared component used by 10 other modules  ,  one module require like this  and another module may require a different thing(  change the label of first input) .   Do we need to handle all these in shared component?   In pur project like wise ,each of the shared components contain like these conditions and LOC become more.

Comment: Okay then you can handle it by passing the flag variable value from the component you are going to render the shared component. I'll Edit the solution

Comment: Even the flags should be handled on conditional basis in shared component  ,if i am not wrong

Comment: Yes you should handle the value of flag with in the shared component using @Input decorator `<shared-component [key] = "keyValueToBeSent" ></shared-component>`  , In shared component `@Input() key:any ` and use key value for your conditons like `this.key`

Comment: ok. Any other way apart from this? this is how it is done in our project right now. the code has grown so much in the shared component , each condition has min of 10 LOC and also each module has independent code .the only concern is about LOC. We are looking for any other approach so that these condition can be handled in individual module. Thanks !

Comment: If you could just upload the code structure and implementation, that would be great to rectify whats happening

Comment: setOrder(index: number): void {
          //check 
          if((this.router.url.indexOf("check") > -1)) {
              ...
            }
            //landing 
            else
    if((this.router.url.indexOf("landing") > -1))  {
               ....
   
           } //test flow
      else if (this.test){
        .....
    
    }
     else if {
          .....
    }
     else if {
         ....
    }
     else if {
          .....
    }
     else if {
         ....
    }    
         } 
    }

Comment: I can just give you an another optimised solution for your currrent approach. If you know the alternatives predefined, then you can use switch case statements rather than multiple If else statements, and with in the case you can send the respective key value to the shared  component

Comment: This is the sample code ,for each condition referring to each module there is min 10 LOC and even shared component html has samething , the div's are made to show and hide based on conditions from the using module.

Comment: the goal is to keep the code as much as possible out of shared component so I am exploring the diff ways.  Since this is a shared module ,if i want to make node module and use it to get imported in another application ,it wil be difficult to manage

Answer (score 0):

Since the shared component is a child component, it can accept @input from the parent component, from reusability and readability point of you, I will suggest you do something like this,

Parent component logic

```
<shared-component [showInputBox]="A Boolean Passed from parent compoent"></shared-component>
```

Shared Component logic

```
@input()showInputBox: Boolean
<div *ngIf="showInputBox">
<input />
</div>
```

Hope this helps, please correct me if I am wrong.